# Java httpClient streaming request

Tags: java, stream, streaming, httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to reproduce some behavior provide by my front end app by using a java http client.

I'm trying to send (stream) binary data from httpClient to server over PUT request. So content type is `application/octet-stream`. I've to send an unknown amount of data that is incoming.

Firstly, I used Apache HttpClient because it can handle digest authentication easily (that's is a requirement). For it, I use `ContentProducer` that enable writing directly to the OutputStream.

Below is an example:

```java
   HttpPut sendDataReq= new HttpPut(
                HTTP_URI);
   ContentProducer myContentProducer = new ContentProducer() {
     @Override
     public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException
     {
       out.write("ContentProducer rocks!".getBytes());
       out.write(("Time requested: " + new Date()).getBytes());
     }
   };
   HttpEntity myEntity = new EntityTemplate(myContentProducer);
   sendDataReq.setEntity(myEntity );
   HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(sendDataReq);
```

I expect from this piece of code to stream request (AND NOT RESPONSE) from client to server.

By using Wireshark, I'm able to see my PUT request but it is send over TCP protocol and then nothing. When I try to listen using my front end web app, I can see that the PUT request is sent over HTTP protocol with 0 content length, data is then sent bytes by bytes (packet of some amount of bytes)  over HTTP protocol with a log info: CONTINUATION.

Also, I tried with httpUrlConnection but there is no digestAuthentication implementation. So, I give up to use it.

Any hints of what is bad in my `ContentProducer` and how to accomplish it? Using other java HTTP clients? I can provide Wireshark log of what is expected and what I have.